# Elasticsearch does not return existing document sometimes

Tags: elasticsearch

For the existing document when I fire following cURL command, I get:

```
root@unassigned-hostname:~# curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/test3/573553/"
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "test3",
  "_id": "573553",
  "exists": false
}
```

When I fire the same command second time, I get:

```
root@unassigned-hostname:~# curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/test3/573553/"
```

result:

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "test3",
  "_id": "573553",
  "_version": 1,
  "exists": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": "573553",
    "name": "hVTHc",
    "price": "21053",
    "desc": "VGNHNXkAAcVblau"
  }
}
```

I am using Elasticsearch 0.90.11 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Could anyone please help me figuring out this problem?

Comment: What do mean by 'sometimes', if you run the second request again is the document available?

Comment: I have tried running second request multiple times and for some of them I get document available and for remaining no document. Random requests work well so I have used word 'sometimes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen cases where elasticsearch shards can get out of sync during network partitions or very high add/update/delete volume (the same document getting updated/deleted/added within milliseconds of each other, potentially racing). There is no clean way to merge the shards, instead, you just randomly choose a winner. One way to check if this is the case is to repeatedly run a match all query and check if the results jump around at all.

If you want to roll the dice and see what happens you can set replicas down to 0 and then bump back up to whatever value you were using.

While this may not be the reason for your issue, it is worth noting this is one of the reasons not to depend on elasticsearch as your primary source of truth.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful! How you would typically quantify "very high update volume"?

Comment: Clarified above, basically add/update/delete for same document coming in pretty much concurrently or maybe with a few ms between, but you likely need your source submitting to be using multiple threads concurrently.